# cannot write to file which is busy by another process exp, multi Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, file

Hello i have problem with putting logs using multithreading, my function loks like this

```
    public static void AddToLog(string message)
    {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(ExeDir + @"\logs.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter mStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    mStreamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                    mStreamWriter.WriteLine(message + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "." +
                                            DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
                    mStreamWriter.Flush();
                }
            }
    }
```

And well , i create this object each time, so i can't lock it, problem is when i am opening it, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Save yourself some lines by `using(StreamWriter writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(path)){writer.WriteLine("line");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is already static, if you are using one instance of the application just add

```
  private static object logLock = new object();
  public static void AddToLog(string message)
  {
     lock(logLock)  // or with a timeout
     {
        ...
```

But I think @Mark has the better advice to use a special library.

Comment: thanks, i used your solution for now, but i will change it as Mark advised. thanks you both.

Answer (score 4):

> I have problem with putting logs using multithreading

You should use a logging library. There are many available for .NET, such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html). See also:

- [What is your .NET logging framework of choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126540/what-is-your-net-logging-framework-of-choice)

If you want to implement it yourself then factor the logging out of your application into a single component. Open the file once when your application starts and perform the logging via a well defined interface with the appropriate synchronization in the implementation. Don't directly write to the same log file from lots of different places in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the FileShare modifier as well (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx)

(but +1 for logging library suggestions)